# Pyrogram handler not working when trying to call the function

Tags: python, telegram, handler, pyrogram

```py
filter_  = (filters.me & ~filters.forwarded & ~filters.incoming & filters.via_bot & filters.command(".", ["ascii"]))

async def hello(client, message):
     await message.reply("HELLLO WORLD")

app.add_handler(hello, filter_  )
app.start()

idle()
app.stop()
```

It just always goes into a loop, nothing more.
It does not work, no  reply by the client.
What's wrong in it? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [`MessageHandler()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/handlers#pyrogram.handlers.MessageHandler).

```py
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler

...

app.add_handler(MessageHandler(hello, filter_))
```

See [Update Handler](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/handlers) in the documentation for a reference.

---

While this is unrelated to your original question, I believe [Decorators](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/decorators) to be a better alternative, as they don't require an additional import or instantiation:

```py
from pyrogram import Client
app = Client()

@app.on_message(filter_)
def hello(client, message):
    await message.reply("hello")

app.run()  # This app.run() call also skips app.start(), idle() and app.stop()
```

---

Edit to reply to the ["answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67600930/10045952) below:
For what you're testing you're using way too complicated filters.

```py
filter_ = (
    filters.me  # Messages that you sent
    & ~filters.forwarded  # Not messages that were forwarded
    & filters.incoming  # Messages this session received
    & ~filters.via_bot  # No "via @samplebot" (ie no inline bots)
    & filters.command(".", ["dict", "define", "meaning"]  # The crux of your issue.
)
```

The [Command Filter](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/filters#pyrogram.filters.command) takes three arguments. `commands`, `prefixes`, and `case_sensitive`. Since you're not using named arguments (`arg=value`) you need to keep them in order.
Only the first argument is required and needs to be a single string, or a list of strings (for multiple commands). If not specified, `prefixes` will default to `"/"` and commands need to be like `/this` to trigger. Since you have the arguments in the other order, you're messing up the command filter.

You need to switch the argument for your command filter around ([see docs](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/filters#pyrogram.filters.command)) or, better yet, start with the [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you were asked for when creating a question.

Comment: it didnt works vro, i;m tagging and giving u full code below

Comment: Thanks vro, i'm new to pyro really helps <3